# Loading custom functions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've got some additional functions that I've defined in an additional PowerShell script file, that I'm trying to load in a main .ps1 file. However, when I call the .ps1 file from the PowerShell prompt it doesn't seem to run through those commands.

In the following code example, build_functions.ps1 has code that defines various custom functions. If I run the file separately (for example, running it by itself and then running through the primary script) it works fine. Build_builddefs.ps1 contains a number of variables that also need to be populated prior to running the primary script.

At the beginning of my primary script I have this:

```
.\build_functions.ps1
.\build_builddefs.ps1
```

However, these don't seem to be run, because the primary script fails when it tries to execute the first custom function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nice link on loading functions at PS startup: https://sandfeld.net/powershell-load-your-functions-at-startup

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have to `dot source` them:

```
. .\build_funtions.ps1
. .\build_builddefs.ps1
```

Note the extra `.`

This `heyscriptingguy` article should be of help - *[How to Reuse Windows PowerShell Functions in Scripts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-to-reuse-windows-powershell-functions-in-scripts/)*

Comment: If I do not know the source path, how can I find out?

Comment: @Timo check my answer ;)

Comment: Also, you can run `dir function:`  after that to make sure the function got loaded.

Answer (score 43):

I kept using this all this time

```
Import-module .\build_functions.ps1 -Force
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to @manojlds because dot sourcing doesn't allow a user to "undo" the dot sourcing. With `Import-Module` you can easily remove the module by `Remove-Module Build_Functions`

Comment: It's best to avoid using `Import-Module` with regular `.ps1` scripts (as opposed to `.psm1` files, which are true modules), because it can create conceptual confusion. In effect, `Import-module .\build_functions.ps1 -Force` is the same as `. .\build_functions.ps1` - simple dot-sourcing, no actual modules involved (except for a pseudo module showing up in `Get-Module` output). Therefore, @FrankFu, you can _not_ use `Remove-Module` to unload such definitions later - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209077/45375) for details.

Answer (score 1):

[KERR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906794) is IMO the only "valid" one.
Relative paths given like in most answers won't resolve from the script's path but from `PWD`...

Here is how to load relative files:

```
$parent_dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

. $parent_dir\Scripts\prompt.ps1
. $parent_dir\Scripts\aliases.ps1
. $parent_dir\Scripts\isoTools.ps1
```

You can find more informations about Automatic Variable [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#myinvocation)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to load one from a specific path/directory:

```
. "C:\scripts\Function-Search-AD.ps1"
```

[image]