# Load script into a PowerShell console via an alias

Tags: windows, powershell

To load a script file into an open PS console (e.g. to import functions) dot-sourcing or the Import-module applet is needed.

Using this inside a function (to create an alias) doesn't work, e.g.:

```
Function psinit1 { . C:\Scripts\scriptFunktions.ps1 }
Function psinit2 { Import-module C:\Scripts\scriptFunktions.ps1 -force}
```

when I call `psinit1` or `psinit2` I don't get an error, but my functions are not available. Why doesn't this work, am I right in assuming that the function opens a new scope which loads the script (and gets closed once the function is done)?

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you invoke a function via [`.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), the *dot-sourcing* operator, its body executes in a *child scope*, so that any operations you perform inside of it - unless you explicitly target  a different scope - are limited *to that child scope and its descendant scopes*.

Therefore, to make your functions works as intended, i.e. to make definitions visible to the *caller's* scope, dot-source *their invocations* too:

```
. psinit1
```

Generally, note that while [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) *also* accepts `.ps1` *scripts*, its primary purpose is to act on [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules). With `.ps1` scripts, it effectively behaves like dot-sourcing, except that *repeating* an `Import-Module` call with a `.ps1` script in a child scope fails, unless `-Force` is also specified (to force reloading).

The upshot: **Do not use `Import-Module` with `.ps1` scripts**:

- The primary reason to avoid is that it makes a promise it cannot keep: because simple dot-sourcing takes place, no actual *module* is being imported - even though one *nominally* shows up in [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module)'s output, named for the script file's base file name (e.g., `foo` for script `foo.ps1`).
- Because simple dot-sourcing takes place, you can *not* use [`Remove-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-module) to *unload* the script's definitions later; while you can *call* `Remove-Module` on the imported pseudo-module, it *has no effect*: the dot-sourced definitions remain in effect.

Comment: Thx, I got the idea to use Import-Module on a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758913/2089396) on StackOverflow in order to unload the functions again, which I couldn't get to work yet (but I only gave it a brief trial so far). Except for not being best practice is there an actual downside to using Import-Module (-force) for scripts?