# How to log output of imported PowerShell module to a log file

Tags: powershell, file, logging, import-module

I have a PowerShell Script that is importing a module and I am calling this module.  However, this module has lots of useful output that I am not capturing and I would like to write it to a file.  What is the best way to do this?

Example code:

```
Write-Host "Loading modules.." -ForegroundColor Cyan

Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\cleanupFile.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Get-FullFilePath.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Initialize-DiskPartition.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Initialize-VHDPartition.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\MountVHDandRunBlock.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\New-TemporaryDirectory.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Run-Executable.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Set-DiskPartition.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Set-VHDPartition.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\Wim2VhdClass.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\private\cleanupFile.ps1
Import-Module C:\Users\Dev1\Downloads\WimConvertTest\WindowsImageTools\Public\Convert-Wim2VHD.ps1

try
{
    Write-Host "========================== Creating VHDX ================================== "
    Convert-WIM2VHD -Path ".\os_1.vhdx" -SourcePath ".\os_1.wim" -Size 16GB -force -DiskLayout UEFI 
    # How to send output from imported module to a "_Convert-WIM2VHD.log"
    # Example: powershell -Command "Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Wait -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"...?
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $Error[0]
    Write-Host $Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName
```

What is the best way to get all the output from Convert-WIM2VHD to _Convert-WIM2VHD.log?

Comment: As an aside: It's best to avoid using `Import-Module` with regular `.ps1` scripts (as opposed to `.psm1` files, which are true modules), because it can create conceptual confusion. In effect, `Import-module .\foo.ps1 -Force` is the same as `. .\foo.ps1`, i.e. simple _dot-sourcing_ - no actual modules involved (except for a pseudo module named `foo` showing up in `Get-Module`'s output). Therefore, you can _not_ use `Remove-Module` to unload such definitions later - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209077/45375) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to send output from imported module to a "_Convert-WIM2VHD.log"

**From *inside* PowerShell**:

- To capture output *only* in a file, use a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection): to capture output from *all* PowerShell [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams),  use `*>`

  ```
  Convert-WIM2VHD ... *> _Convert-WIM2VHD.log
  ```
- To *also* capture output in a file, while *still outputting it* (to the success output stream, which prints to the display by default), use [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object); combine with a `*>&1` redirection in order to capture all streams:<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```
  Convert-WIM2VHD ... *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath _Convert-WIM2VHD.log
  ```
- To *also* capture output *from an entire script or session*, use [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) and       [`Stop-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript):

  ```
  Start-Transcript _Convert-WIM2VHD.log
  # ... commands or script calls whose output to capture
  #     You can also build these calls into your script.
  Stop-Transcript
  ```
- In a [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call, the *only* way to capture any output is in files, namely via `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError`, but note:

  - There's usually *no* reason to use `Start-Process` to invoke *console* applications - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375); [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.
  - Capturing *combined* stdout and stderr output isn't directly possible, though when calling the *PowerShell* CLI, specifically, even PowerShell error output is sent to stdout (see below). For other programs, you'd have to call *via a shell* (such as PowerShell) in order to merge the streams - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76093799/45375).

---

**From *outside* PowerShell**, when calling the the PowerShell *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+):

- Because the PowerShell CLI sends *all* its output streams to *stdout* - including the *error* stream - a simple `>` redirection from a calling shell (e.g. `cmd.exe`, Bash) is sufficient; e.g.:

  ```
  powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '...' > _Convert-WIM2VHD.log
  ```

  - However, if you request a (separate) *stderr* redirection (`2>`), PowerShell's error stream *is* sent to stderr (but none of the *other* non-sucesss streams).
- **Note**: While this send-everything-to-stdout-by-default behavior happens to be convenient for this use case, it is generally problematic: arguably, all streams other than the *success* output stream should be sent to *stderr* - see [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989).

---

**Character-encoding considerations**, i.e. what character encoding is used in the output files:

- **From *inside* PowerShell**:

  - **`>`**, as an effective alias of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), uses the latter's default encoding:

    - UTF-16LE ("Unicode") in *Windows PowerShell*.
    - BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* (BOM-less UTF-8 is the *consistent default* there).
    - To choose a different encoding, use `Out-File` explicitly, with its `-Encoding` parameter (but then you cannot combine it with `Tee-Object`).
  - **`Tee-Object`** with `-FilePath` uses:

    - UTF-16LE ("Unicode"), *invariably* in *Windows PowerShell*
    - BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* by *default*; in v7.3+, the `-Encoding` parameter can be used to change that.
  - **`Start-Object`** with `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardOutput`:

    - *Invariably* uses the console window's output code page (see below).
- **From *outside* PowerShell**:

  - On *Windows*, the PowerShell CLI (in both editions) uses the console window's output code page (as reported by `chcp`), which defaults to the system's active legacy *OEM code page*, such as [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems.

    - This means that for full Unicode support you'll have to switch the calling console window to UTF-8 first (`chcp 65001`); since Windows 10 it is also possible to configure a system to use UTF-8 *system-wide*, in which case both the OEM and the ANSI code page are set to `65001` (UTF-8). However, this has *far-reaching consequences* in that it can change the behavior of existing console applications and PowerShell scripts; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for details as well as a PowerShell-only alternative.
  - Un *Unix*-like systems, the PowerShell CLI (`pwsh`, the PowerShell (Core) CLI) invariably outputs (BOM-less) *UTF-8*-encoded text.

---

<sup>[1] Note that this by design merges all streams into the *success* output stream (which is what makes it possible for `Tee-Object` to see *all* output) and therefore "pollutes" the latter; for *display* output that doesn't matter, however.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Kris.